# Android cannot resolve R error and Some file crunching failed error for images

Tags: android, image

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>
> > Some file crunching failed, see logs for details

and other logs:

> :app:clean :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:checkDebugManifest :app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2340Library
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72340Library
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42340Library
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2340Library
>   :app:prepareDebugDependencies :app:compileDebugAidl
>   :app:compileDebugRenderscript :app:generateDebugBuildConfig
>   :app:mergeDebugShaders :app:compileDebugShaders
>   :app:generateDebugAssets :app:mergeDebugAssets
>   :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugResources
>   :app:mergeDebugResources AAPT err(Facade for 4833051): libpng error:
>   Not a PNG file AAPT err(Facade for 4833051): libpng error: Not a PNG
>   file AAPT err(Facade for 16006587): libpng error: Not a PNG file

I have those images now:

```
b3_1.jpg
b3_3.jpg
giphy.gif
ic_back.png
ic_forward.png
ic_launcher.png
ic_mainactivity_logout.png
ic_mainactivity_result.png
img_mainactivity_background_placeholderimg.jpg
s.png
```

I tried to change all image names to good ones.

I put `ic_` to the beginning, can it be problem? I wanted to make them icon. They are already in use also.

I changed one or two images with jpg to png, with refactor. Can it be reason?

Now `R class` seems unimported. I did not change anything. I only rebulded cleaned after all tries.

Answer (score 0):

When packing your resources, Gradle has detected that one of your PNG images is not a PNG, it's probably a JPG or GIF with the wrong extension.

As you have very few images, try to locate the offending file and rename it appropriately.

"refactoring" a image file does not change its structure, just the name. If you want to convert a JPG to a PNG you must use an external tool.

Comment: Is it important jpg or png?

Comment: Regardless the format you use, the files have to have the correct extension.  JPEG is a Lossy format (your image will lose quality in favour of more compression) while PNG is Lossless ( and normally bigger). The choice is yours, it's a balance between file size and quality.